# Java strange problem

Tags: java, android

I am bit poor at java or better to say OOP's I have a strange problem, I wonder if thats possible. I have a class

```
private ArrayList<?> data;
public A(Activity a, ArrayList<?> mStatus)
{
    activity = a;
    data = mStatus;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}
```

later i used

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View vi = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_gallery, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
        holder.root = (LinearLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.root);
        vi.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

    //I used this that solves my problem
    if(data.get(position) instanceof GalleryTestParser)
    {
        GalleryTestParser mParser = (GalleryTestParser)data.get(position);
        holder.text.setText(mParser.Name);
        holder.image.setTag(mParser.galleryThumbiPad);
        holder.root.setTag(mParser);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(mParser.galleryThumbiPad, activity, holder.image);
    }


    return vi;
}
```

**Edit: Above I want if data is of type GalleryTestParser or if some other than do something else.**

earlier I was trying `ArrayList<GalleryTestParser> mStatus` in constructor but that is class specific. What I want is that from object of arraylist somehow I must know what type of it is so that I type cast arraylist object to that type.

Is that possible ?

Comment: post the whole class, what's the type of `data`?

Comment: So your problem is that you don't know which type of object is in your ArrayList but nevertheless you want to cast it to the correct type?

Comment: @Roflcoptr yes exactly .I want that I can pass arraylist of any type and later I would cast it to that type only

Comment: Assuming for a moment that this were possible: what possible use would it have? You couldn't call any methods on it, because those methods would be available on a specific type that you don't know at runtime. Can you tell us **what** you want to do with the correctly-cast object? Then we might be able to tell you how to approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on StevieB's answer (and adding a twist): You can use an interface along with a unique key to identify which concrete class you are dealing with:

```
public abstract interface GenericParser {
    public String getType();
}

public class GalleryTestParser implements GenericParser {
    public String getType() {
        return "gallery";
    }
}

public A(Activity a, List<? extends GenericParser> mStatus) {
    GenericParser item = mStatus.get(0); 
    if (item.getType().equals("gallery")) {
        item = (GalleryTestParser)item;
        // Do stuff with item
    }
}
```

This avoids "instanceof", giving you more control over the handling. For example, getType() could return something more complicated in future, like a list of capabilities.

Ideally though, you might want to move the execution into the GalleryTestParser, which will make the code cleaner:

```
public abstract interface GenericParser {
    public void execute();
}

public class GalleryTestParser implements GenericParser {
    public void execute() {
        // Do stuff with item
    }
}

public A(Activity a, List<? extends GenericParser> mStatus) {
    GenericParser item = mStatus.get(0); 
    item.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
public A(Activity a, List<? extends GenericParser> mStatus)
```

and then subclass the different types of parser from the generic base.

Careful though, if you need to use instanceof to tell them apart you are probably doing it wrong,
really only the parser should need to know what type it is!

Comment: Alternatively to using instanceof: the GenericParser interface can declare getType(), which GalleryTestParser would implement and return something unique like "gallery"...

Comment: Hi as I told I am poor in oops :P can you provide link to code sample

Answer (score 1):

Do you need an `instanceof` operator?

```
if (mStatus.get(i) instanceof GalleryTestParser){
    GalleryTestParser parser = (GalleryTestParser) mStatus.get(i)
}
```

This practice isn't good though.

Comment: your method solves my problem but I am waiting for some better option BTW +1

Answer (score 0):

Change your signature to

```
public A(Activity a, List<GalleryTestParser> mStatus)
```

Comment: actually I was trying that only but that makes my class specific to GalleryTestParser and I dont want that I want that I must able to cast arraylist to correct type

Comment: So, you have some differenet parsers? Make an interface to implement for them and mention it in List< HERE >.